# webkit bug: input's background gets gray without any reason on focus?

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, webkit, border

I just encountered a very annoying bug, and hard to track down. But let us get to the point:

- **WEBKIT ONLY** (Safari, Chrome, etc. - I reproduced this on Safari 5.1 and Chrome 13 on **Mac OS Lion**)
- Mac OS only? (Comments suggest this, need more input from other users)

Just go to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wjGLq/1/) and focus the input: **It's background turns gray**! (See screenshot at [Chromium Bug Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=92962))

---

When you change the css in either the following ways, the error is gone:

- change color not something not completely white (`255,255,254,0.6`)
- remove transparency (`255,255,255,1`)
- change double-type border to any other (`4px dotted rgba...`)
- change thickness to <3px (`2px double...`)
- add `display: inline;` to the css of the `<h2>` (or change the tag to an inline displayed one)

So the it looks like the bug is only triggered when:

- the `color` of the border is exactly `white` with some `transparency`
- it must be of `type double`
- it's `thickness` must be `greater than 2px`
- the element must be `positioned block`
- it doesn't matter if some absolute positioned elements are in between the html-code ([see axample](http://jsfiddle.net/wjGLq/2/)): it has to do something with the rendered position of the elements

**Why is it doing this? Is this a webkit bug or is there any reason behind this?**

---

Another mention worthy thing is: The css of the block-element modified (`<h2>` in my example) has NOTHING to do with the input - but yet it triggers the bug. You can imagine how hard it was to debug this on a page with some more elements between these two ...

---

*Possible Workaround*:

Do not use completely white background, but: `rgba(255, 255, 254, 0.6)`. Human eye does not notice it. But using this feels uncomfortable. Anything better?

---

Also on [Chromium Bug Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=92962) now with screenshot

Comment: Have you logged the bug on the [Chromium bug tracker](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/entry)?

Comment: The fiddle works fine for me on Chrome 13. No gray background that I can notice.

Comment: I can't repro with any WebKit browser on Windows 7. Looks like it's a Mac thing, or at least not a Windows thing.

Comment: just done so: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=92962

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not reproducible any more with latest webkit versions. Problem solved itself.