# CSS rgba transparency bug in Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, transparency, rgba

Just placing a DIV with white background and any opacity value:

```
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
```

over a white (255x3) background. Actually DIV's background will be 254/254/254. This happen only in Chrome. FF/IE/Opera/Safari is ok.

Bug?

Comment: I don't see it in Chrome - do you have an example?

Comment: <body style="background:white;">
 <div style="background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); width:200px; height:200px;">abc</div>
</body>
As Möhre said you should have good display to see this.

Comment: Here's a photo of the bug (Chrome 36): http://s13.postimg.org/ql29ma96f/white.png

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a bug!

I can confirm this misbehaviour. Got it also by using `background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1)`. More weird: the calculated style says `background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0980392)`

It is hard to see on cheaper displays using TN technology, but still possible to screenshot and measure with e.g. Photoshop.

This question is similar to:
[webkit bug: input's background gets gray without any reason on focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071345/webkit-bug-inputs-background-gets-gray-without-any-reason-on-focus)

Answer (score 3):

The weird behaviour is still present in Chrome 38 and Canary 40. The fix that worked for me was to add a `transform: translateZ(0);` to the div with the rgba background.

Answer (score 1):

This can now be fixed with the new `will-change` property. Specifically, `will-change: transform;`